# (De)serialization QSet with enum using QDataStream

Tags: qt, enums, qdatastream, qset

I use Qt 4.8.7. I have `enum Color {red, green, blue}` and `QSet<Color>`. How should I (de)serialize `QSet<Color>` using `QDataStream`? Deserialization fails with custom type. Should I manually create serialization (loop over QSet elements) besides deserialization? I mean that internal serialization implementation for QSet in theory can be changed by Qt developers, so I have to write two loops for serialization/deserialization by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following cast for deserialization in order to avoid creating manual loops:

```
data_stream >> reinterpret_cast<QSet<qint32>&>(color_set2);
```